# Passing attributes from one shapefile to another that does not share line or segment?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, data-transfer

I am struggling to convert attributes from one shapefile to another. The issue is that the geometry is not the same.

How is it possible to pass attribute values from one layer to another considering they don't match ? See below an example.

[image: Screenshot of overlayed features]

Comment: Could you be more precise : what kind attributes do you have, what is the geometry type, etc. ? The answer depends on the details as it's not a simple thing to do.

Comment: Both the shapefiles are polylines. There are 3 colomns I want to transfer. Some of the attributes are the same in both shapefiles, but not all af them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  **[Attribute Transfer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment-attribute-transfer.htm)**, on ArcGIS Spatial Adjustment toolbar does what you require, but you have to do it manually, by clicking the source feature and the target feature. It is simple enough if your editing is limited.

You can set its parameters to transfer several attribute if needed. The "Auto Match" option will build the attribute pairs (source-destination) if the attribute names are identical ; else you can build the list of source-destination attributes manually.

Detailed help on this is [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/transferring-attributes-between-features.htm).